# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; comma not missing

Tags: mysql

I am getting below error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog` (
`Blog_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Blog_Name` va' at line 53
```

Below is my code,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog` (
  `Blog_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Blog_Name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `User_User_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Blog_Url` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Blog_Sort` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Blog_Parent` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Blog_Status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Blog_Date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Blog_Publish` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Blog_Content` mediumblob
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I have seen similar questions on StackOverflow and the problem with their code was it had an extra comma. My issue seems to be different.

EDIT:
Below is the code which is just above it,

```
--
-- Table structure for table `attendance_type`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `attendance_type` (
`Attendance_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Attendance_Code` text,
  `Attendance_Desc` text,
  `Attendance_Meaning` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Attendance_Action` text NOT NULL,
  `Attendance_Action_Group` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `attendance_type`
--

 INSERT INTO `attendance_type` (`Attendance_ID`, `Attendance_Code`, `Attendance_Desc`, `Attendance_Meaning`, `Attendance_Action`, `Attendance_Action_Group`) VALUES
(3, '#', 'School closed to pupils', 'Not counted in possible attendance', 'yes', '5'),
(4, '/', 'Present (a.m.)', 'Present', 'no', '1'),
(5, '\\', 'Present (p.m.)', 'Present', '', '1'),
(6, 'B', 'Educated Off Site (NOT Dual Registration)', 'Appoved Education Activity (Present)', 'yes', '2'),
(7, 'C', 'Other Authorised Circumstance (not covered by other appropriate code/description', 'Authorised Absence', 'yes', '4'),
(8, 'D', 'Dual Registration (ie pupil attending other establishment)', 'Not counted in possible attendance', '', '5'),
(9, 'E', 'Excluded (no alternative provision made)', 'Authorised Absence', 'yes', '4'),
(10, 'G', 'Family Holiday (NOT agreed or days in excess of agreement)', 'Unauthorised Absence', 'yes', '3'),
(11, 'H', 'Family Holiday (Agreed)', 'Authorised Absence', 'yes', '4'),
(12, 'I', 'Illness (NOT medical or dental etc. appointments)', 'Authorised Absence', 'yes', '4'),
(13, 'J', 'Interview', 'Appoved Education Activity (Present)', 'yes', '2'),
(14, 'L', 'Late (before registers closed)', 'Present', 'no', '1'),
(15, 'M', 'Medical/Dental appointments', 'Authorised Absence', 'yes', '4'),
(16, 'N', 'No reason yet provided for absence', 'Unauthorised Absence', 'yes', '3'),
(17, 'O', 'Unauthorised absence (not covered by any other code/description)', 'Unauthorised Absence', '', '3'),
(18, 'P', 'Approved Sporting Activity', 'Appoved Education Activity (Present)', 'yes', '2'),
(19, 'R', 'Religious Observance', 'Authorised Absence', 'yes', '4'),
(20, 'S', 'Study Leave', 'Authorised Absence', 'yes', '4'),
(21, 'T', 'Traveller Absence', 'Authorised Absence', 'yes', '4'),
(22, 'U', 'Late (After registers closed)', 'Unauthorised Absence', '', '3'),
(23, 'V', 'Educational Visit or Trip', 'Appoved Education Activity (Present)', 'yes', '2'),
(24, 'W', 'Work Experience', 'Appoved Education Activity (Present)', 'yes', '2'),
(25, 'X', 'Untimetabled sessions for non-compulsory school-aged pupils', 'Not counted in possible attendance', 'yes', '5'),
(26, 'Y', 'Enforced and partial enforced closure', 'Not counted in possible attendance', 'yes', '5'),
(27, 'Z', 'Pupil not yet on roll', 'Not counted in possible attendance', 'yes', '5'); 

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How do you execute that? The error starts right at the beginning of your statement. Any statements before that, that you execute at the same time?

Comment: @juergend: Its a snippet from a .sql file.

Comment: And what statement comes right before that one? Maybe you forgot a `;` at the end of the previous statement

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/345269/1  What does the rest of your SQL file look like?  The error's probably in a *previous* query.

Comment: What happens immediately BEFORE this query?!?!

Comment: I have updated the question with the code above the mentioned code.

Comment: How are you running/importing the SQL file?  Even with the extra code you added, it still works fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bee1b/1

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by syntax coming before this query, the code here is fine.
[See here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhvs3.png)